# Unable to install ownCloud on RHEL 7 : Dependencies issue?

Tags: yum, rhel, owncloud, rhel7

I have an issue when trying to install ownCloud from yum install (sorry, console is in French, I'll translate words that seems to be important for understanding, so they are not really what they should be in English) :

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install owncloud
Modules loaded : langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos,
                                : subscription-manager
Resolution of dependencies
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Packet owncloud.noarch 0:8.2.1-1.1 will be installed
--> Treatment of dependence : owncloud-server = 8.2.1 for packet : owncloud-8.2.1-1.1.noarch
--> Treatment of dependence : owncloud-config-apache = 8.2.1 for packet : owncloud-8.2.1-1.1.noarch
--> Test transaction
---> Packet owncloud-config-apache.noarch 0:8.2.1-1.1 will be installed
---> Packet owncloud-server.noarch 0:8.2.1-1.1 will be installed
--> Treatment of dependence : php-ldap for packet : owncloud-server-8.2.1-1.1.noarch
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Packet  php-ldap.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1 sera installé
--> Treatment of dependence : php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.el7_1 pour le paquet : php-ldap-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
--> End of Resolution of dependencies
Erreur : Paquet : php-ldap-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
             Needed : php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.el7_1
             Installed : php-common-5.4.41-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
                 php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.41-1.el7.remi
             Available : php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
                 php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-21.el7
             Available : php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
                 php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0
             Available : php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
                 php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.1
             Available : php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
                 php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
             Available : php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
                 php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.el7_1
             Available : php54w-common-5.4.45-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
                 php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-2.w7
             Available : php55w-common-5.5.30-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
                 php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.30-2.w7
             Available : php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
                 php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.14-2.w7
             Available : php56w-common-5.6.15-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
                 php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.15-1.w7
             Available : php56w-common-5.6.16-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
                 php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.16-1.w7
             Available : php70w-common-7.0.0-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
                 php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.0-1.w7

yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enablingdisabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf
```

I don't understand why I have an error that `php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.el7_1` is needed and I have `php-common-5.4.41-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi)` installed...

I tried to reconfigure yum as explained, but the problem is the same. I followed tutorial from ownCloud to install under RHEL 7 (that contains tips to add depot for ownCloud) and problem is the same (https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/owncloud/ ).

I would like to use yum because if I install it manually, I have to update it manually, and it's complicated...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed PHP from "remi" repository which is not enabled by default.

You must enable it to install php-ldap.

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-ldap
```

(notice: this will pull latest version which is 5.4.45)

Comment: Thank you for your help, it solved my issue ! But I don't really understand why : if I remember correctly, I used the packet manager from RHEL to install PHP. Should I use only remi depository or must I delete it and use only official one ?

Comment: EL-7 have 5.4.16 which will be maintained until distro EOL. remirepo  have latest 5.4.45, which is now EOL (security fix will be backported in remirepo for some time). Both should work.